# Explain Hotel Artemis joke about Florida

Tags: dialogue, hotel-artemis

In minute 57:31 of *Hotel Artemis* the nurse says that her ex-husband moved to Florida and that it alone means he has grown desperate of life or something similar...

> Nah. He lives in Florida.
>   Life took him out already.

Can someone explain why is it said so about Florida?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Florida's warm and a lot of people retire there - so more or less, it's famous for having a lot of elderly out of towners. If he's moved to Florida, it means he's tired of his life where he was.

It's a bit of an old old American joke, and basically means he's retired.

Considering the nurse is a cranky old lady who *hasn't* retired - sounds like the sort of thing she'd say.

Comment: Unless you go further down south to Miami or the Keys. Then Florida instantly transforms into culture/night-life. Orlando has culture too, but not to that extent. Orlando has tourism culture.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. For most people, when you say someone went to Florida it means they've given up on life. Florida is where you go to die. Especially if you're leaving a big city like New York or Chicago where all the excitement is or if you're leaving your hometown. Florida has warm weather, but it's considered a cultural wasteland, so it's like you don't want excitement and cukture unless it's the stupid beach kind. I'm sorry if you live in Florida.

Comment: Welcome to the site! While many of your comments may qualify as shared sentiments regarding folks perception of Florida's it isn't good enough to cite that these comments are made "(by) For most people"... please use references if you can to back up what are otherwise considered shared notions among 'most people'.